# Does "two consecutive columns have the same color in every two columns" make sense?

Tags: adverbial-phrases

[image]

The image above shows an Excel worksheet.  I am trying to describe how cells in row 3 are colored. It is not necessary to describe what color it is. My example is as follows:

> Cells in row 3 are colored such that two consecutive columns have the same color in every two columns.

In this image, the number of consecutive columns is two, but I would like to know more general expressions that can be used regardless of the number of consecutive columns, for example, in the sequence of five consecutive colored columns, three consecutive uncolored columns, five consecutive colored columns, three consecutive uncolored columns, five consecutive colored columns, ....

Could you advise me on whether this correctly describes the color pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid I can't make much sense out of your sentence when I compare it to the data you've shown.

The only way I can understand the colour scheme in terms of your use of *consecutive columns* is to talk about **column pairs**.

To describe what I mean:

- The members of the first column pair have the colours green and blue.
- The members of the second column pair have the colours green and red.
- The members of the third column pair have the colours blue and blue.

Based on that, we can say:

> The third column pair has members with the same colour.

Or, more simply:

> The fifth and sixth columns have the same colour.

---

Assuming that this is an actual pattern (and will repeat if we extend the sample), we can express it in the following fashion:

> Every third column pair has members with the same colour.

Or:

> Every fifth and sixth column has the same colour.

---

**Update 1**: Based on a comment, it appears that the question actually involves not just looking at the *coloured* columns but at *all* columns, including those that are *uncoloured*.

Further, you are talking about actual Excel columns, not visually distinguishable columns.

As such, a description of the pattern could now be:

> Each column pair alternates between having its members have the same colour and having its members have no colour.

---

**Update 2**: To accommodate an edit to your question, I need to make a further change to my answer.

To describe an arbitrary number of coloured columns followed by an arbitrary number of uncoloured columns, it now becomes simpler to use a descriptive notation rather than natural language:

> #C-#U

Where each # is a number, C stands for *coloured*, and U stands for *uncoloured*.

In the pattern actually *shown* in the question, the notation would be:

> 2C-2U

In the pattern additionally described, the notation would be:

> 5C-3U

Note that because of this notation, this question and answer is now outside the realm of actual English and might be better served by a different SE site.

Comment: As you pointed out, that pattern repeats. I think "pair" can be used only for two consecutive columns.  I would like to know more general expressions that can be used regardless of the number of consecutive columns, for example, in the sequence of  five consecutive colored columns, three consecutive uncolored columns,  five consecutive colored columns, three consecutive uncolored columns, five consecutive colored columns,  ....

Comment: I've made several updates to my answer, the second based on the edit you made to your question.

Comment: I rewritten it using "alternate" as follows: " Cells in row 3 are colored such that three consecutive columns having the same color repeatedly alternate with five consecutive columns having no color".  Does this make sense?

Comment: @rama9 I believe my final update still applies to whatever scheme you want to apply. The problem is that, unlike the original version of your question, you're asking about a situation that keeps changing. It's not possible to come up with an English description that applies to multiple situations like this. If you change the scenario, the previous answer would need to be rephrased. We can't provide a "general" expression for this type of thing.

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you are not always going to be working with pairs of columns (you speak about five columns and three columns as a possibility), and you seem to be describing an alternating scheme of some kind.

Your attempt is not clear. **in every two columns** doesn't cut it.

> Starting with column A, there are groups of adjacent columns, each
>    group having two or more columns, all columns in the group being of the same color. Between these groups there are two (or more?) adjacent  columns lacking color.

Comment: @rama9: I do not understand your comment.

Comment: You mentioned the word "alternate" and I rewritten my example using "alternate". So I attempted to reply to you, but I noticed that Jason first mentioned the word "alternate" , so I replied to  him. Please refer to Jason's comment section.